# How to make a background with 45 degree lines with css?

Tags: css, css3pie

Using CSS or CSS3, how can i make the folowing background ?

[image: background with 45 degree lines]

If possible, i'd like ie6,7,8 support. I can use a javascript based tool to simulate CSS3 for old browsers (like css3pie).

Comment: I'm just wondering if it is simple to do it with CSS. Otherwise, i will stick with my image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If possible, i'd like ie6,7,8 support.

Use a background image. Even if you could use pure CSS3 to create such a pattern for a background (I highly doubt that is possible), it's not worth the hassle to use a bunch of JavaScript libraries and such just to get it to work in those versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

[I use this.](http://www.stripegenerator.com/)
Then you just do background-image:url(blahblahblah.gif)

<del>Any reason you're still supporting IE6? It would be easy to do without IE6 support.</del> IE really sucks for gradient support, so you'll need to use an image, but here's the CSS anyway.

```
background-color: #0ae;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
```

I know this probably doesn't match your image. I'm sorry, but your image host is blocked by my work, so you'll have to interpret from here. This will work with webkit browsers and FF3.6, and will fall back to the color specified in `background-color` for non-compliant browsers.

Comment: More like without any IE support at all.

Comment: You have to add the -ms- version too, for IE10.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a repeating texture square. Find a small ping and use a repeating backround.

Comment: Not an answer... a {ping?} PNG is an image.  The OP is asking for a CSS solution.